# "No current user" when making unauth Appsync API call for public DB tables

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

There really isn't enough documentation on this either in the AWS docs or in the Github, so hopefully someone here has tackled a similar issue.

I have a react app with backend api hosted on AWS, using appsync, dynamoDB, and cognito-user-pools. My IAM policies are set up to allow unauth users read-only permission to some public tables. I tried the public api key but that didn't do anything. I'm trying to get the IAM unauth role permissions set up but even when I experimentally added literally every service and every action to the unauth role, I still get "no current user" when attempting to make the API call without logging in.

Use case is for public author pages, where information about an author along with their currently available books is listed. Users should not have to sign in to see this page, an author should be able to drop a link to the page to anyone, whether they have a login for the app or not.

This is my graphql schema for the relevant types, it gets no errors:

```
type PublicBook @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete], provider: userPools },
{allow: public, operations: [read], provider: iam}])
@key(name:"byPublicWorld", fields: ["publicWorldId", "indexOrder"])
@key(name:"byPublicSeries", fields: ["publicSeriesId", "indexOrder"]){
  id: ID!
  publicWorldId: ID
  publicSeriesId: ID
  indexOrder: Int!
  cover: FileObject @connection 
  description: String 
  amazon: String
  ibooks: String
  smashwords: String 
  kobo: String 
  goodreads: String 
  audible: String 
  barnesnoble: String 
  sample: String
}
type PublicSeries @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete], provider: userPools },
{allow: public, operations: [read], provider: iam}])
@key(name:"byPublicWorld", fields: ["publicWorldId", "indexOrder"]){
  id: ID!
  publicWorldId: ID!
  indexOrder: Int!
  logo: FileObject @connection 
  description: String
  genre: String
  books: [PublicBook]@connection(keyName:"byPublicSeries", fields: ["id"])
}
type PublicWorld @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete], provider: userPools },
{allow: public, operations: [read], provider: iam}])
@key(name:"byAuthorPage", fields: ["authorPageId", "indexOrder"]){
  id: ID!
  authorPageId: ID!
  logo: FileObject @connection
  description: String
  genre: String 
  indexOrder: Int!
  series: [PublicSeries]@connection(keyName:"byPublicWorld", fields: ["id"])
  books: [PublicBook]@connection(keyName:"byPublicWorld", fields: ["id"])
}
type AuthorPage @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete], provider: userPools },
{allow: public, operations: [read], provider: iam}])
@key(name:"byPenName", fields: ["penId"])
@key(name:"byPenDisplayName", fields: ["penDisplayName"], queryField: "authorPageByPen"){
  id: ID!
  authorName: String 
  penDisplayName: String
  penId: ID!
  bio: String 
  photo: FileObject @connection 
  logo: FileObject @connection
  penFBProfile: String
  penFBGroup: String
  penFBPage: String
  penTwitter: String
  penInstagram: String
  penAmazon: String
  penWebsite: String
  penNewsletter: String
  penGoodreads: String
  penPatreon: String
  posts: [AuthorPost]@connection(keyName:"byAuthorPage", fields: ["id"])
  worlds: [PublicWorld]@connection(keyName:"byAuthorPage", fields: ["id"])
}
type AuthorPost @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete], provider: userPools },
{allow: public, operations: [read], provider: iam}])
@key(name:"byAuthorPage", fields: ["authorPageId", "timeCreated"]){
  id: ID!
  authorPageId: ID!
  timeCreated: AWSTimestamp!
  content: String!
  title: String!
  subtitle: String
  type: PostType!
}
```

Each of these types is set to owner/cognito permissions for creating, updating, and deleting, and then there is a public auth using iam to read. Seems straight forward enough.

The main type here is Author page, and I have the query set up to pull all the connected relevant cascading information. When logged in, this works fine and shows an author page with all the bits and bobs:

```
export const authorPageByPen = /* GraphQL */ `
  query AuthorPageByPen(
    $penDisplayName: String
    $sortDirection: ModelSortDirection
    $filter: ModelAuthorPageFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    authorPageByPen(
      penDisplayName: $penDisplayName
      sortDirection: $sortDirection
      filter: $filter
      limit: $limit
      nextToken: $nextToken
    ) {
      items {
        id
        authorName
        penDisplayName
        penId
        bio
        photo {
          location
        }
        logo {
          location
        }
        penFBProfile
        penFBGroup
        penFBPage
        penTwitter
        penInstagram
        penAmazon
        penWebsite
        penNewsletter
        penGoodreads
        penPatreon
        posts {
          nextToken
          startedAt
        }
        worlds {
          nextToken
          startedAt
        }
        _version
        _deleted
        _lastChangedAt
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        owner
      }
      nextToken
      startedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

On the page itself (although in production this just happens at app.js and persists throughout the app), I'm pulling current credentials and logging them to make sure that some kind of IAM identity is being created, and it appears to be:

```
accessKeyId: "BUNCHANUMBERSKEY"
authenticated: false
expiration: Thu Mar 04 2021 13:18:04 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) {}
identityId: "us-west-2:48cd766c-4854-4cc6-811a-f82127670041"
secretAccessKey: "SecretKeyBunchanumbers"
sessionToken:"xxxxxbunchanumbers"
```

That `identityId` on line 4 is present in my identity pool as an unauth identity, so it *is* getting back to the pool, which seems to be what's supposed to happen.

So, this identity pool has two roles associated with it, which is standard: auth and unauth, and my Unauthenticated Identities Setting has the box for `Enable Access to Unauthenticated Identities` checked.

In my unauth role, I've got the following as the inline policy json:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "appsync:GraphQL"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:appsync:us-west-2:MyAccountID:apis/MyAppsyncApiId/types/Mutation/fields/authorPageByPen"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wasn't sure if this needed to be mutation, or query, or what, so I've tried them all. I tried them in combination with 'fields' and with 'index', I've tried writing the JSON, and adding the policies from the inline editor, which gives me the following which also does not work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "appsync:GraphQL",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:appsync:us-west-2:MyAccountID:apis/MyAppSyncAPIId/types/AuthorPage/fields/authorPageByPen",
                "arn:aws:appsync:us-west-2:MyAccountID:apis/MyAppSyncAPIID"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What bit am I missing here? I could understand getting some error about not being allowed to access a resource, but the only error that logs is `No Current User`, and that happens immediately after the log *showing* the user.

Update:
Running the query from the Appsync console works fine with IAM and no logged in user. In the page itself, I'm using the following function to call the author page (I'm using routes):

```
const pullAuthorPage = async () => {
        try{
            const authorPageData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(authorPageByPen, { penDisplayName: props.match.params.id.toLowerCase() }))
            console.log(JSON.stringify(authorPageData, null, 2));
            setState({...authorPageData.data.authorPageByPen.items[0]})
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

What I *thought* would happen with this is that if there is no authenticated user logged in, this will run using the unauth user credentials. Is that not the case? And if so, how should I change it?

Comment: The FileObject from the table isn't shown but it has the same public read policy, and it pulls from a public bucket where all the images (that's all that's stored there) are set to public. Those work, I can put in the location URL and they show just fine.

Comment: I tried adding policies for all the associated tables (authorPageByPen index pulls information from all associated tables), still no dice.

Comment: Update: When I run the query from appsync, it returns data using "IAM" policy. So, all I can think of is that there's some reason that the front end isn't sending the proper header, maybe? Post updated with the query function I'm using on the page.